# android package manager can not work  with ICS

Tags: android, linux, shell, adb

Before 4.0,It's work normally, but after 4.0,I can't run it like "pm uninstall com.abc"

my code like this:

```
try {
                // Executes the command.
                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm uninstall me.onemobile.android");
                DataOutputStream toProcess = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
                toProcess.writeBytes("exec " + "shell pm uninstall me.onemobile.android" + "\n");
                toProcess.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
```

when I run it,it's show like this:

```
[1] + Stopped (signal)
```

There some difference when i run "pm uninstall com.test" in root,and it just show

```
[1] + Stopped (signal)
```

but when run "adb shell pm uninstall com.test" ,It's work, so it's make me crazy.

any help or hint will be appreciate.

Comment: That's not a public interface.  Use an Intent if you want to begin the process of removing a package.  It is a design requirement of Android that the user is then asked to confirm the removal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
  toProcess.writeBytes("export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib:/system/lib" + "\n"); 
  toProcess.writeBytes("exec " + "shell pm uninstall me.onemobile.android" + "\n"); 
  toProcess.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem in android 4.0.3.
after running 'adb su', 'pm' always return [1] + Stopped (signal).
It seems cause by the privilege.

Comment: I have solve it ,just try add this before pm:"LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib:/system/lib